# Android Project (API 19 , Kitkat 4.4.2) In Phonegap on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks not creating

Tags: android, ios, macos, cordova

I was trying to create a PhoneGap project for multiple platform. First I Create a iOS Project and everything went fine.And it was running correctly.The problem arose when trying to create a android app in phone gap using command line

```
phonegap build android
```

that time terminal showing this error

```
[error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.
```

How to get rid of this situation. This forced me to use previous phoneGap versions. Any Suggestions would be really thankful.

Comment: do you have ant installed and added to your PATH?

Comment: yup.. Did successfully

Comment: Can you echo your PATH for us? Also, try running `phonegap build android -d` to see more debug information.